# Press On Hold Off Power Switch

Tags: power, button

Hi everyone I am hoping someone here can help me.
I am trying to make an arduino turn my project on and off.Using a relay.
I am looking for it to act like a computer power button.
A short press to turn on and them stay on and a long press (say 5 sec) to turn off and then stay off till button is pressed again.
I would like it so that the project can not be accidentally turned off
Can anyone please help.
Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far, and what part is giving you difficulty? If you need a hint to get started, you code will need to store the relay state (on/off), measure the time of  each button-press, and compare the time to the length of a short-press or long-press, depending on the current state.

Comment: Hi JRobert after spending the best part of 2 days looking around the web. Reading posts looking at you tube videos. I cant find an example to do this. The Arduino IDE as a button on, off, example in it. But I need a long press to turn off. To prevent accidental power off. Basically I want a pin to go high on a short press. and only go low if it sees a long press of say 5 secs. So if the button is pressed accidentally it will do nothing unless the press is long.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a test sketch that I wrote for a different question. The other question's requirement was for a short press (minimum 100ms) to turn on an LED, and a long press (1 second) would turn it off. With a slight modification of this sketch, it may work for you. You will need to install the `Bounce2` library.

```cpp
// Press and hold button for 100 ms to turn LED ON.
// Press and hold button for 1000 ms to turn LED OFF.
#include <Bounce2.h>

byte buttonState = 0;
const byte ledPin = 3;
const byte buttonPin = 2;
const unsigned long debouncerInterval = 50;
unsigned long buttonPressedTime = 0;
unsigned long currentMillis = 0;

Bounce debouncer = Bounce();

void setup(){
  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
  debouncer.attach(buttonPin, INPUT_PULLUP);
  debouncer.interval(debouncerInterval);
}

void loop(){

  // Get the current time.
  currentMillis = millis();

  // Check if button was pressed or released.
  if(debouncer.update()){

    // Pressed.
    if(debouncer.read() == 0){
      if(buttonState == 0){
        buttonState = 1;
        buttonPressedTime = currentMillis;
      }
    }

    // Released.
    else{
      buttonState = 0;
    }
  }

  // Turn the LED ON or OFF.
  if(buttonState == 1){
    if(currentMillis - buttonPressedTime >= 1000){
      digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
      buttonState = 0;
    }
    else if(currentMillis - buttonPressedTime >= 100){
      digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help it works great. I just changed the buttonPreeedTime from 1000 to 5000 and it dose everything I wanted... Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

To clarify the problem, do you want to control ON OFF using Arduino? It is very simple. Please read this [simple](https://www.electroschematics.com/arduino-control-relay/) tutorial, and modify it according to your needs.

Comment: This is not what @David Boswell is trying to do. A short button press turns on the relay, and the user must press and hold the button down for 5 seconds to turn the relay off. The button in the link of the tutorial turns the relay on, then automatically turns the relay off after 5 seconds has elapsed.

Comment: @VE7JRO yes of course with small modification. jees.

Comment: You hit the nail on the head..VE7JRO. that is what i need to do. Press and hold to turn off